# Multiple variables for the intercept (random slopes) of a Mixed Effect Model (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4

I am a newbie in R, coming from STATA. I want to evaluate a mixed model (lme4) where my dependent variable is a means (mean speed) and I have as independent variables crosswalk, approach_width (these two in one level, street or approach), lumix, pop_dens, and empl_dens (these ones in another level, this level is the intersection). For the different levels, I have an ID (Int_ID and Approach_ID). 
The idea is to evaluate the effect on means that lumix, pop_dens, and empl_dens in the Int_ID level and crosswalk, approach_width in the Approach_ID have.

I have been trying to find the way to specify different random slopes on lmer function without any success. I know if I just want to evaluate the Int_ID and Approach_ID should be something like this:

```
memeads <- lmer(means ~ crosswalk + approach_width + lumix + pop_dens + empl_dens + (1 | Approach_ID) + (1 | Int_ID), data = db)
```

In STATA I'd do something like this:

```
xtmixed means crosswalk approach_width lumix pop_dens empl_dens || Int_ID : lumix pop_dens empl_dens || Approach_ID : crosswalk + approach_width
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you getting a specific error or just want to know the best way to accomplish this? please share some of your data using `dput(db)` so others can help.

Comment: Adding my vote to mike's comment. A snippet of your data will be useful in understanding your problem. If you have the time reading their quite excellent guide [Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models using lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) is an option. While it is lengthy it will give you the in-depth knowledge of how to construct mixed models using the `lme4` package.

Comment: Hi @mike, I want to know the way to add more variables to the random slopes with this model.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks a lot, I will check this paper, I already read a lot before posting here my question trying to find out the solution for this. But for sure this paper will help me to understand what's behind the model

Comment: I am glad i could help. As for your second comment to mike, random slopes (check the table on page... 7 i believe in the linked documentation) are performed as `(slope | random effect)`. Multiple effects can be made either by adding a `+` after each random effect, or using the same format for each random slope variable.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver . I am able to fit the model know with the lecture and your suggestion in the comment. I posted the solution here also. Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Oliver's help, I was able to fit my model. The solution is the following if any in a future.

To have more than one random variable in the slope, the model would be:

```
memeads <- lmer(means ~ crosswalk + approach_width + lumix + pop_dens + empl_dens + (1 + lumix + pop_dens + empl_dens | Approach_ID) + (1 +crosswalk + approach_width | Int_ID), data = db)
```

Thanks for the support